# Strange website behaviour - if anchor ID exists on current page, doesn't redirect menu link to correct url

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

The anchor links on this webpage: https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/ are behaving very strangely.

They work if navigating from an outside page like the homepage or about page. As soon as you click on any of the nested menu items under:

- "Services" -> "Court Construction" -> any of the anchor links, or
- "Services" -> "Court Surfacing" -> any of the anchor links.

Trying to navigate to any of the other anchor links, which each lead to a different page, doesn't work if the ID (`#install` or `#resurfacing`) exists on the current page. It just navigates up and down to that section on the current page.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Menu HTML below:

```
<div class="fxb-col fxb fxb-end-x fxb-center-y fxb-basis-auto site-header-main-right-top">
                                <div class="sh-component main-menu-wrapper" role="navigation" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">

                    <div class="zn-res-menuwrapper">
            <a href="#" class="zn-res-trigger zn-menuBurger zn-menuBurger--3--s zn-menuBurger--anim1" id="zn-res-trigger">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </div><!-- end responsive menu -->
        <div id="main-menu" class="main-nav mainnav--sidepanel mainnav--active-bg mainnav--pointer-dash nav-mm--dark zn_mega_wrapper "><ul id="menu-construction-menu" class="main-menu main-menu-nav zn_mega_menu "><li id="menu-item-1145" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home menu-item-1145  main-menu-item-top  menu-item-even menu-item-depth-0"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-top"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1146" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-1109 current_page_item menu-item-1146 active  main-menu-item-top  menu-item-even menu-item-depth-0"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/about-us/" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-top"><span>About</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1698" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1698  main-menu-item-top  menu-item-even menu-item-depth-0"><a href="#" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-top"><span>Services</span></a>
<ul class="sub-menu clearfix">
    <li id="menu-item-1779" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1779  main-menu-item-sub  menu-item-odd menu-item-depth-1"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/court-construction/" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Court Construction</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu clearfix">
        <li id="menu-item-1741" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1741  main-menu-item-sub main-menu-item-sub-sub menu-item-even menu-item-depth-2"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/basketball-court#basketball-install" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Basketball Court</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1794" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1794  main-menu-item-sub main-menu-item-sub-sub menu-item-even menu-item-depth-2"><a href="/tennis-court/#install" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Tennis Court</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1795" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1795  main-menu-item-sub main-menu-item-sub-sub menu-item-even menu-item-depth-2"><a href="/pickleball-court#install" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Pickleball Court</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1796" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1796  main-menu-item-sub main-menu-item-sub-sub menu-item-even menu-item-depth-2"><a href="/multi-use-court/#install" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Multi-Use Court</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-1699" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-1699  main-menu-item-sub  menu-item-odd menu-item-depth-1"><a href="/court-surfacing" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Court Surfacing</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu clearfix">
        <li id="menu-item-1737" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1737  main-menu-item-sub main-menu-item-sub-sub menu-item-even menu-item-depth-2"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/basketball-court#basketball-resurfacing" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Basketball Court</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1758" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1758  main-menu-item-sub main-menu-item-sub-sub menu-item-even menu-item-depth-2"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/tennis-court#resurfacing" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Tennis Court</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1755" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1755  main-menu-item-sub main-menu-item-sub-sub menu-item-even menu-item-depth-2"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/pickleball-court#resurfacing" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Pickleball Court</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1765" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1765  main-menu-item-sub main-menu-item-sub-sub menu-item-even menu-item-depth-2"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/multi-use-court#resurfacing" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Multi-Use Court</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-1701" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1701  main-menu-item-sub  menu-item-odd menu-item-depth-1"><a href="/" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-sub"><span>Custom Court Installation</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1148" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1148  main-menu-item-top  menu-item-even menu-item-depth-0"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/projects-2/" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-top"><span>Projects</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1305" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1305  main-menu-item-top  menu-item-even menu-item-depth-0"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/equipment/" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-top"><span>Shop Equipment</span></a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1306" class="main-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1306  main-menu-item-top  menu-item-even menu-item-depth-0"><a href="https://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/contact/" class=" main-menu-link main-menu-link-top"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul></div>     </div>
        <!-- end main_menu -->
        <a href="http://victoriaplayco.gotbdev.com/contact/" class="sh-component ctabutton cta-button-0 kl-cta-custom btn btn-fullcolor btn-sm zn_dummy_value cta-icon--before btn--rounded" target="_self" itemprop="url"><span>READY? GET YOUR QUOTE NOW!   </span></a>       </div>
```

Comment: I would try breaking down the page to the absolute minimum. Just a link to a page that has the # at the end of the URL that matches an object with that same ID on that same page and that's it. And if that works build up from there until you have the problem again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, it sounds like you're describing the current issue. The menu items are links to pages with #s at the end that include IDs that match objects on the current page, but clicking on them doesn't lead to the URL specified

Comment: I'm talking about stripping your page of everything except for the absolute basics to be able to duplicate the problem. If the problem doesn't exist when you strip it down, then start building it up piece by piece until you are able to experience the problem again then you know that last piece was the problem.

Comment: This might be a JS issue/conflict with a plugin. Try disabling plugins and then activate them one by one, testing the menu after each activation.

Comment: They are working for me under chrome.  I must admit it took a while to figure out what you meant, because the layout of the menus is baffling.  Once i am on a page the anchors work fine